# How do you override bootstrap 3 styles with external custom CSS?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

How do you override bootstrap 3 styles with external custom CSS?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href = "css/bootstrap.min.css" rel = "stylesheet"/>
<link href = "css/styles.css" rel = "stylesheet"/>


<div class = "navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top"></div>
```

CSS

```
.navbar-inverse {
    background-color: #FF0000;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are a few things to consider:

- **Stylesheet order** - The stylesheet you are trying to overwrite should come first.

  > [**6.4.1 Cascading order**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#cascade)
  >
  > Finally, sort by order specified: if two declarations have the same weight, origin and specificity, the latter specified wins. Declarations in imported style sheets are considered to be before any declarations in the style sheet itself.

  In you case this shouldn't be an issue.

  ```
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <link href="css/overwrite.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  ```

---

- **Selector specificity** - Read up on [specificity (mdn)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

  Put briefly, you should use a selector with the same specificity *(assuming it appears later and will overwrite the initial declaration)*, or a selector that is more specific.

  Bootstrap 3's default styling uses the following for the `navbar`'s color:

  ```
  .navbar-inverse {
      background-color: #222;
      border-color: #080808;
  }
  ```

  You could try using a more specific selector:

  ```
  .navbar.navbar-inverse {
      background-color: #FF0000;
  }
  ```

---

- **Stylesheet paths** - If all else fails, your stylesheet path(s) must be wrong.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
   .navbar-inverse { 
        background-color: #FF0000 !important; 
    }
```