# Override Bootstrap Multiselect CSS to my custom CSS class

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, multi-select

I am using bootstrap multiselect dropdown. But I am not able to change it my custom CSS style.

```js
 $(function () {
        $('[id*=lstMarket]').multiselect({
            //buttonWidth: '250px',
            includeSelectAllOption: true,
            buttonContainer: '<div class="searchParam" />'
        });
    });
```

```css
div.searchParam         {display:inline-block; padding-right:10px; padding-bottom:10px;}
    td.searchParamBox       {padding:10px 10px 0px 10px; border: 3px solid #0079C2; vertical-align:middle; background-color:#C3DFE5; border-top-left-radius: 7px; border-bottom-left-radius: 7px;}
    td.searchBox            {color:#FFFFFF; padding:10px 10px 10px 10px; border: 3px solid #0079C2; background-color:#0079C2; vertical-align:middle; border-top-right-radius: 7px; border-bottom-right-radius: 7px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="searchBox">
   <tr>
      <td class="searchParamBox">
          <div class="searchParam">
              Market<br />
                <asp:ListBox ID="sqllstMarketConfigId" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple" Width="100%" CssClass="searchParam">
                    <asp:ListItem Text="list1"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="list2"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="list3"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="list4"></asp:ListItem>
                </asp:ListBox>
           </div>
       </td>
     </tr>
</table>
```

I have tried in different ways but none of them are worked out.

Comment: Could you provide a list of things you've tried already?

Comment: use `!important` it overrides that particular property.

Comment: @EmmaEarlKent I tried to call my custom class in a jquery which you can see above, and I have tried giving a CSS class directly to the listbox.

Comment: @Omi I have tried !important. Not working

Comment: what you want to do?

Comment: Checkout this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25655805/how-do-you-override-bootstrap-3-styles-with-external-custom-css) for three things to try: Stylesheet order, Stylesheet specificity, and Stylesheet paths